# How to get location data on phones browser as we get on pc browser

Tags: javascript, html, web, location

I Was working on a project where I was making a web application to get a weather report of your location.
but i ran into an issue that it is **supporting in pc/desktop computer**
but **not phones**

*So, I need your help*

**this is my present code which supports in pc/desktop computer:-**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Weather Report</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Weather Report Of your location</h1>
        <hr>
        <p id="location"></p>
        <p id="data"></p>
        <script>
            var data_of_Lat_Lon = document.getElementById("location");
            var data = document.getElementById("data");
            var Latitude;
            var Longitude;
            var key = "-------------------------------";<!--put your key-->
            var url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?";

            function getLocation(){
                if(navigator.geolocation){
                    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
                }
                else{
                    data_of_Lat_Lon.innerHTML="Geolocation is not supported by this browser. SORRY!";
                }
            }

            function showPosition(position){
                data_of_Lat_Lon.innerHTML=("Latitude: "+position.coords.latitude+
                "<br>Longitude: "+position.coords.longitude);
                
                Latitude = position.coords.latitude;
                Longitude = position.coords.longitude;

                getData(Latitude,Longitude);
            }

            function getData(Lat,Lon){
                const readyToSent = (url+"lat="+Lat+"&lon="+Lon+"&appid="+key);   
                fetch(readyToSent)
                .then(response=>response.json())
                .then(data=>{
                    console.log(data);
                    fetchData(data)
                })
            }

            function fetchData(data){
                document.getElementById("data").innerHTML =
                    "The weather report of your Location is :-<br>"+
                    "Location:-<br>"+
                    "Country :"+data.sys.country+
                    "<br>Local Area Name :"+data.name+
                    "<br>Temp. :"+data.main.temp+
                    "<br>But You will feel like :"+data.main.feels_like+
                    "<br>Min. Temp. :"+data.main.temp_min+
                    "<br>Max. Temp. :"+data.main.temp_max+
                    "<br>Pressure :"+data.main.pressure+
                    "<br>Humidity :"+data.main.humidity+
                    "<br>Weather :"+data.weather[0].description
            }
            getLocation();
            showPosition();
            getData();
        </script>
        <hr>
        <p>Made By:- Sukarna Jana</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

please troubleshoot my issue that why it is not working at phones.\

> THANK YOU, FOR GIVING YOUR PRECIOUS TIME

Answer (score 1):

This may be because you're not hosting the website at a HTTPS location. You can try turning on treat origins as secure in your chrome flags on mobile.

chrome://flags/#unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure

as for iOS, you'll need to use HTTPS.

(if this doesn't work out to be the case, then location services may be turned off on the phone)

Comment: I just checked that it is working on some other phone browser but not the phones chrome browser... But it's work on computer Chrome smoothly...     If you can elaborate and explain me then it will be really great full. Sorry

Comment: Is your website HTTPS? or HTTP? (is there a padlock in the top left when you visit the page)

Comment: I am calling a API for getting that JSON file of the weather report from OpenWeatherMap so it's http

Comment: The way you said it's doesn't solve the problem remains the same. Sorry... but I appreciate that you came forward and help me. Thank You

Comment: If it's HTTP, sorry, `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()` doesn't work on HTTP origins. It's a security feature, you'll need to switch to HTTPS.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation_API